# How to use Excel VLOOKUP function with words that begin with the letters AB

Tags: text, excel-formula, vlookup, worksheet-function

I have a list of words that I use for title naming. As I create more names, I want to check to ensure I am not duplicating previously used words. My Excel formula seemed to work fine, until I hit words that begin with the letters AB (i.e. absolute, abolished...) that I have not previously used.

=IF(VLOOKUP(B48,Used!A:A,1)=B48,"USED","")

| New Word | Result | Formula Commentary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pretend |  | ...VLOOKUP(B48,Used!A:A,1)=B48 correctly returns FALSE because it did not find the word |
| Abundant | USED | ...VLOOKUP(B48,Used!A:A,1)=B48 correctly returns TRUE because it did find the word |
| Absolute | #N/A | ...VLOOKUP(B48,Used!A:A,1)=B48 returns #N/A when it does not find any word that begins with AB |

I've tried using the TEXT function in the formula to format B48, but no change.
I've tried using Range_Lookup in the VLOOKUP syntax, but no change.

I suspect there is something going on with Excel thinking the AB letter sequence is part of another FUNCTION.

Any insight, guidance, and/or direction is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you lookup `"AB"` in Excel, it does not search for a value that starts with it, but for a value that equals it. If you want to lookup any word starting with `"AB"` you have to tell Excel by adding a wildcard:
`=VLOOKUP(B48&"*",Used!A:A,1,0)`

Comment: I'm not specifically looking for words that begin with AB.  I encounter a problem when using VLOOKUP to search through a list of words, for a specific word.  When that specific word begins with the letters AB, the VLOOKUP fails to return a TRUE or FALSE result, instead returning #N/A.

Comment: Do you mean `=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(B48,Used!A:A,1)=B48,"USED",""),"")`?

Comment: Thank you @P.b IFERROR bypasses the problem, but why is the #N/A being generated? I'd like to understand why the problem exists instead of simply working around it, unless of course it is a bug or some other systemic issue that cannot be addressed more directly.

Comment: The VLOOKUP function returns error `N/A` if you try to lookup a value that's not there. VLOOKUP syntaxes to find the matching row of the search value and return the value in the same row the Nth column. If it doesn't find the value it doesn't know from which row to show the data, so it returns an error. Excel does not consider an error as true or false, so your `IF` function returns `N/A` as well.

Comment: So why does my formula work properly for all other words not in the list, and only returns #N/A for words not in the list beginning with the letters AB?

Comment: I see you're missing an extra argument in your VLOOKUP: `=VLOOKUP(B48,Used!A:A,1,0)` where tho `0` is `FALSE` which is the argument for exact match. This is what Microsoft says about it: If range_lookup is TRUE or left out, the first column needs to be sorted alphabetically or numerically. If the first column isn't sorted, the return value might be something you don't expect. Either sort the first column, or use FALSE for an exact match. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

Comment: The Range_Lookup argument within the VLOOKUP is not missing, it's not required, and while maybe not clear, I have tried True, False, and leaving it out, with no impact to the problem being encountered.

Comment: VLOOKUP always requires the column number to return out of your search range. The exact/approximate (true/false) argument is optional, but advise is to use `false` or `0`, for exact match for text strings. If you still insist on not using the argument, you need to make sure your search range is sorted. But for the purpose you're using it for it shall be an exact match for the argument. You could also use `COUNTIF` for your purpose: `=IF(COUNTIF(Used!A:A,B48)>1,"USED","")`

Comment: Thank you @P.b your COUNTIF formula will not work in this scenario, because it will count the inclusion of a word, for example ABOLISH and ABOLISHING, as in the list when only ABOLISHING is in the list. Again, I'd like to understand why the problem exists instead of simply working around it, which your IFERROR formula already accomplishes.

Comment: Both VLOOKUP and COUNTIF will only return/count exact matches, not including ABOLISH if it's not listed.